# Verifying user is part of ldap/active directory security group

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

Ok... I've dug through the examples and etc on here and I'm still having issues.

```
<?php
// SHOW ERRORS 0=NO 1=YES
ini_set('display_errors', '1');


//USER
$valid_session_username = $_POST["username"];
$valid_session_password = $_POST["password"];

//MEMBER OF THIS GROUP
$dn = "DC=FLRC,DC=local";
$group = "CN=Internet-Purchasing-Allowed,OU=Security Groups,DC=FLRC,DC=LOCAL";
$filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(memberOf=$group))";


$ad = ldap_connect("srv-flc-dc03") or die("Couldn't connect to AD!");
ldap_set_option($ad, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,3);
ldap_set_option($ad, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS,0);
$bd = ldap_bind( $ad, $valid_session_username."@flrc.local", $valid_session_password) or die("Can't bind to server.");
$sr = ldap_search($ad, $dn, $filter);


$found = false;

if ($sr !== false) {
    $count = ldap_count_entries ($ad, $sr);
    if ($count !== false && $count > 0) {
     $found = true;
    }
}

if ($found === true) {
    print $valid_session_username.' does have access to this page';
} else {
    print $valid_session_username.' does NOT have access to this page';
}


?>
```

I have no idea what I'm missing. When I submit my credentials it says "SRAY does have access to this page". Which is what it is suppose to say since SRAY is part of that group. It also says this for another username/pass that is NOT part of that security group.

Answer (score 1):

Your filter is looking for **any** user that is a direct member of the Internet-Purchasing-Allowed group.  You need to add (sAMAccountName=$valid_session_username) to your filter.

Comment: Also, note that if you need to resolve nested group memberships you'll need to use the LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN against Active Directory, which looks like `memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=`. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475(VS.85).aspx for more information on Search Filter Syntax.

Comment: @hall72215 thanks... that did it... something so simple completely shut me down. 

and for JamieSee... Thanks as well I will keep that in mind. Not sure exactly what you are speaking of. I'm a noob to this ldap stuff.

Answer (score 0):

1. You must define **sAMAccountname** in your filter

   ```
   //MEMBER OF THIS GROUP
   $dn = "DC=FLRC,DC=local";
   $group = "CN=Internet-Purchasing-Allowed,OU=Security Groups,DC=FLRC,DC=LOCAL";
   $filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountname=".$valid_session_username.")(memberOf=".$group."))";
   ```
2. You must bind the LDAP with an account that has the necessary rights. Create an administrator **account that has read permissions** on all the "OU=Security Groups". Then bind with it in your code.

   ```
   $bd = ldap_bind( $ad, $admin_session_username."@flrc.local", $admin_session_password) or die("Can't bind to server.");
   ```